# Assigning an argument to an assignment?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to assign a bool argument to an assignment, but I don't know how to assign to an an assigment

Here is my code.

```
 private string ReadName(out bool success)
        {
            string name = "";

            success = name = Nametxt.Text; // not working because of two equal signs 


          return name;
        }
```

I was able to do it with an int variable. This is how I did it with a int.

```
private int ReadAge(out bool success)
        {
            int age = 0;

            success = int.TryParse(Agetxt.Text, out age);

            if (!success)
                MessageBox.Show("The entered age is not valid!");

            return age;
        }
```

Also it there a way to make the ReadName method print error (like the ReadAge method) if the name variable returns non-alphabetic values?

Thank you

Comment: what is not working? what are you trying to do in your method? what determines the success and failure?

Comment: The first one doesn't compile because success is a `bool` and name is a `string`, not "because of two equal signs".

Comment: @Selman22 I don't know how to assign the success to ´name = Nametxt.Text;´. The purpose is to check the input from the user.

Comment: @mikez But it worked on the int variable on the ReadAge() method

Comment: @Simon it works because TryParse returns a `bool` not because there is only 1 equal sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignments in C# return the value that is assigned. The issue you noticed isn't because there are two equals signs, it's because the types don't match.

For example, this will yield the same value as calling the `NameTxt.Text` getter directly.

```
Console.WriteLine(name = NameTxt.Text);
```

The returned value is also the same type as the assignment.

Just as I can't say,

```
bool testBoolean = "true";
```

you can't assign the result of a string assignment to a `bool` output parameter.

If you're looking to validate input, you'll have to provide some way of doing that validation. For example,

```
name = NameTxt.Text;

success = name == "yes";
```

Or

```
success = Regex.IsMatch(name, @"\d");
```

Regardless of what method of validation you use, you need to specify it. You can't depend on the compiler to just know what you hope to accomplish.

The reason `int.TryParse` returns a `bool` is because parsing an int doesn't always work--strings can contain just about anything, but there are very few sets of characters that can correctly map to integers. That's a built-in form of validation.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a string value won't fail, so you can just set the variable to `true` if you need it. You won't need the variable for the value either, just return the value:

```
private string ReadName(out bool success)
{
  success = true;
  return Nametxt.Text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. Tack så mycket!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something similar to `int.TryParse` for a string, in which it will fail if there are any numbers (or non-alphabetic characters) in the string.

You can use a Regular Expression to test for alphabetic characters, like the one below. The `IsMatch` method will test the input string against the expression, and will return true if all the characters are only a-z or A-Z.

```
private string ReadName(out bool success)       
{
    string name = "";

    success = Regex.IsMatch(Nametxt.Text, "^[a-zA-Z]+$");

    if (!success)
        MessageBox.Show("The entered name is not valid!");
    else
        name = Nametxt.Text;

    return name;        
}
```

Comment: Sure. You can put any 'valid' characters in the square brackets, so if you want to allow a space, you could put one between the lower and uppercase checks, for example: `"^[a-z A-Z]+$`